# Angularjs ng-show using scope data from api call

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-show

I'm trying to use the ngShow directive using data from an API call, but can not seem to get it to work properly.

My Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('apiCallController'[$scope,'$http',function($scope,$http{

    $http.get(sampleUrl)
    .success(function(data){
    $scope.sampleData = data
    });

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<label>User Name: {{sampleData.userName}}</label>
<div ng-show="'{{sampleData.member}}' === 'true'">
  <label>Enter Email:</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

When I run the code, all of the data shows up properly when I check the DOM explorer in browser, but the ngShow directive is not working properly.  The div does not display even if though the expression is true.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Sorry ahead of time for the poor formatting, as you can probably tell this is just a replication of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the curly brackets and single quote

```
<div ng-show="sampleData.member === 'true'">
  <label>Enter Email:</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

if `sampleData.member` value type is Boolean then remove the equal true also

```
<div ng-show="sampleData.member">
      <label>Enter Email:</label>
      <input type="text">
</div>
```